# How to start several jobs in different screen sessions in a Bash-script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, gnu-screen

The program I want use can be started via

```
./myprogram < input_part1.txt > output_part1.txt
```

How can I start four jobs of `myprogram` in a `BASH`-script where each job runs in a separate `SCREEN`-session? The sessions do not exist before I start the script.

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -mdS test1 ./myprogram < input_part1.txt > output_part1.txt
screen -mdS test2 ./myprogram < input_part2.txt > output_part2.txt
screen -mdS test3 ./myprogram < input_part3.txt > output_part3.txt
screen -mdS test4 ./myprogram < input_part4.txt > output_part4.txt
```

but this does not work. Why not?

Comment: > 2014
> still using screen

Comment: @tijage: solutions with an alternative are also welcome. But I can not guarantee, that this solutions run on the machines I want to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a single session, I use something like that:

```
cat > screenrc-test <<EOF
screen -t test1 sh -c "./myprogram < input_part1.txt > output_part1.txt"
screen -t test2 sh -c "./myprogram < input_part2.txt > output_part2.txt"
screen -t test3 sh -c "./myprogram < input_part3.txt > output_part3.txt"
screen -t test4 sh -c "./myprogram < input_part4.txt > output_part4.txt"
EOF

screen -S test-all -c screenrc-test
```

I don't know why you want several sessions, but the syntax is, in a similar way:

```
screen -mdS test1 sh -c "./myprogram < input_part1.txt > output_part1.txt"
```

for each session. Using a shell is necessary for the redirections, otherwise the redirections would be applied to the `screen` command instead of `myprogram`.

An example:

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -mdS test1 zsh -c "repeat 4 { date; sleep 1; } > out1"
screen -mdS test2 zsh -c "repeat 4 { date; sleep 1; } > out2"
screen -mdS test3 zsh -c "repeat 4 { date; sleep 1; } > out3"
```

After running it (and waiting for 4 seconds), I get:

```
==> out1 <==
Tue Sep  2 09:23:07 CEST 2014
Tue Sep  2 09:23:08 CEST 2014
Tue Sep  2 09:23:09 CEST 2014
Tue Sep  2 09:23:10 CEST 2014

==> out2 <==
Tue Sep  2 09:23:07 CEST 2014
Tue Sep  2 09:23:08 CEST 2014
Tue Sep  2 09:23:09 CEST 2014
Tue Sep  2 09:23:10 CEST 2014

==> out3 <==
Tue Sep  2 09:23:07 CEST 2014
Tue Sep  2 09:23:08 CEST 2014
Tue Sep  2 09:23:09 CEST 2014
Tue Sep  2 09:23:10 CEST 2014
```

showing that the commands are run in parallel.

Comment: I think in that case all jobs will be started successively, right? So, after `./myprogram < input_part1.txt > output_part1.txt` is finished `./myprogram < input_part2.txt > output_part2.txt` will be started?

Comment: @Chrispie No, the commands are run in parallel. I've just added an example. The reason is that in both cases, the *screen* lines (the ones in the screenrc or the ones with the `-md` option) return immediately.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is exactly what I was searching for.